# Alternative to Using Global Variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have developed a function which runs a query and then uses the resulting variables in a logic in another file.  I have used global variables to achieve this.  I have read global variables are to be avoided, is there another way to write this function to avoid use of global variables.

File 1 (Function File)

```
<?php 

    function usertype() 
    {

        include "../classes/sessionstart.php";
        include "../config/dbconnect.php";

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $select = $con->prepare("SELECT user_usertype, user_gender FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id = $user_id");
        $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $select->execute();
        while($data=$select->fetch()){

            $GLOBALS['gender'] = $data['user_gender'];  
            $GLOBALS['usertype']  = $data['user_usertype'];
        }
    }

?>
```

File 2 (File Using the Function File)

```
<?php
    usertype();
?>
<div>
    <select class="searchpropertyinputs" name="user_usertype" id="user_usertype">
        <?php if ($gender == "Male" && $usertype != "Marriage Bureau") { ?> <option value="Bride">Bride</option> <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($gender == "Female" && $usertype != "Marriage Bureau") { ?> <option value="Groom">Groom</option> <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($usertype == "Marriage Bureau") { ?>
            <option value="" hidden>Bride or Groom</option>
            <option value="Bride">Bride</option>
            <option value="Groom">Groom</option>
        <?php } ?>  
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, just pass whatever your function needs as parameters. And don't construct queries with string interpolation.

Comment: return an array of data from the first function, and pass that array to the next function as pvg is saying.  Use placeholders with your prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the value from the function:

Updated code, also fixed prepared query, and set an alias for the return columns.

```
<?php

    function usertype() 
    {
        include_once "../classes/sessionstart.php";
        include_once "../config/dbconnect.php";

        $select = $con->prepare("
            SELECT user_usertype as `type`,
                   user_gender   as `gender`
            FROM tbl_user
            WHERE user_id = :user_id LIMIT 1
        ");
        $select->bindValue(':user_id', (int) $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $select->execute();

        return $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

?>
```

.

```
<?php
    $usertype = usertype();
?>
<div>
    <select class="searchpropertyinputs" name="user_usertype" id="user_usertype">
        <?php if ($usertype['gender'] == "Male" && $usertype['type'] != "Marriage Bureau") { ?> <option value="Bride">Bride</option> <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($usertype['gender'] == "Female" && $usertype['type'] != "Marriage Bureau") { ?> <option value="Groom">Groom</option> <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($usertype['type'] == "Marriage Bureau") { ?>
            <option value="" hidden>Bride or Groom</option>
            <option value="Bride">Bride</option>
            <option value="Groom">Groom</option>
        <?php } ?>  
    </select>
</div>
```

You may also want to move out the `includes` to connect, session start, or you will have issues for future functions. So that should most likely lead you on to grouping functions into a user class, for example:

```
<?php

include_once "../classes/sessionstart.php";
include_once "../config/dbconnect.php";

class User {

    public function __construct(PDO $con)
    {
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function type($user_id = 0) 
    {
        $select = $this->con->prepare("
            SELECT user_usertype as `type`,
                   user_gender   as `gender`
            FROM tbl_user
            WHERE user_id = :user_id LIMIT 1
        ");
        $select->bindValue(':user_id', (int) $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $select->execute();

        return $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    //...
}

$user = new User($con);

$usertype = $user->type($_SESSION['user_id']);
?>
```

Comment: I'd also pass in `$con` instead of including it in presumably via `dbconnect.php`. That seems like it would be creating a new connection each time (just guessing)

Comment: Thanks for your help I am getting the following error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in commonqueries.php:11 Stack trace: #0 matrimonialprofilesearch.php(48): usertype() #1 {main} thrown in commonqueries.php on line 11

Comment: Added a class, which may help the OP.

Comment: $select->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); this is working instead of  $select->bindParam(':user_id', (int) $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: That's because `bindParam` works with a variable *reference*. You cannot cast the variable to a primitive in that case

Comment: all fixed, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, also for the OOPs answer, thanks.

Comment: np, happy coding :)